# Query in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

**PROBLEM**

Hello! I need to do query where I response all tasks who have `list_id = id` and also I need to response all sub tasks who have `task_id = taskID`. But I can't figure out how to make right query for `taskID`..

**MY CODE**

```
$response['lists'] = Lists::findorfail($id);
$response['tasks'] = Tasks::latest()->where('list_id','=',$id)->get();
```

Upper code work properly, i get all tasks by list id.

```
$taskID = Tasks::latest()->where('list_id','=',$id)->get('id');

$response['subtasks'] = Subtasks::latest()->where('task_id','=',$taskID)->get();
```

At the moment I have this query, but it's not working, I just show it to better explain what I want to do.

[There is image to see what I meant, how it must look like, when work properly](http://s2.postimg.org/9j9tglggp/How_must_look.png)

In that image you can see, that I have 2 tasks on list (i get it using upper code), on that popup form you can see that 1st task have 2 sub tasks (same as 2nd task), so i want to make query to output right sub tasks for each task.

```
$response['subtasks'] = Subtasks::latest()->where('task_id','=',4)->get();
```

I use this NOT correct code, just to show example. `'task_id','=',4` this mean that I get all sub tasks for task with `id = 4`. But every task now have these sub tasks. So i need query to get task id automatically and output right.

I hope you understand what I want to get.

**RELATION STRUCTURE**

[There you can see relationships of tables.](http://s8.postimg.org/9ouxpb5j9/Relation.png)
[There you can see output after adding code from answer.](http://s8.postimg.org/anp2wtn0l/Output.png)

Comment: can you clarify your data structure: does list - task relation is 1-to-many or 1-to-1? and what is your $response array format you expect?

Answer (score 0):

This line of code:

```
$taskID = Tasks::latest()->where('list_id','=',$id)->get('id');
```

will return a collection with elements are Tasks with list_id = $id

so you cant not use $taskID as id number in your query like:

```
$response['subtasks'] = Subtasks::latest()->where('task_id','=',$taskID)->get();
```

Instead you can do something like this:

```
// this will return an array of taskID
$taskIDs = $response['tasks']->pluck('task_id');

// then you can do it like 
foreach ($taskIDs as $taskID) {
    $response['subtasks'][$taskID] = Subtasks::latest()->where('task_id','=',$taskID)->get();
}
```

Updated: you can also use like this:

```
//This will return a collection of all subtasks    
$subtasks = Subtasks::latest()->get();

//This will turn subtasks in to group according to tasks_id
$response['subtasks'] = $subtasks->groupBy('task_id');
```

for all method related to Collection of Laravel you can refer it [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#collection-method)

Regards,

Comment: I just try to use your code, but I get empty array `subtasks`. I also updated my question with link where you can check my relationship and output what I get after adding your code.

Comment: `$taskID = Tasks::latest()->where('list_id','=',$id)->get('id');` and also this code didn't return anything.. I got error that I must return array, but return string or something like that. I write it just to show structure of query..

Comment: Ah, I make 1 mistake the first query should be: `$taskIDs = $response['tasks']->pluck('id')`. It should work. Btw, I've added more solution to the question, please check.